# A scikit-learn encoder for "Null/Not Null"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a number of variables in a dataset that are both a) sparse and  b) unique (mostly...). Something like this:

`Foo
NaN
NaN
Bar
NaN
NaN
NaN
Baz`

While the actual value of these variables is interesting in some contexts, I often find myself just replacing them with True/False for Null/Not Null.

I was wondering if this exists as an encoder for scikit-learn -- andif it doesn't, does anyone have an idea of how to implement it?

Comment: np.isnan(array)? or pd.notnull() depending on the type of object you use to represent your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
class NullNotNullTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Transforms data according to null/not-null scheme.
    """
    def fit(self, X):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return pd.isnull(X)
```